# Mystery Excel semicolon mode for data validation, stops recognizeing standard comma for unknown reason

Tags: vba, excel, validation

In Excel VBA how can I set cell validation so that it works in all locales?

#### This code works in my locale, semicolon separated

```vb
Dim mySheet As Worksheet
Set mySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 1")
Dim myRange As Range    
Dim validValues as String
validValues = "a;b;c"
Set myRange = mySheet.Cells(2, 2)
myRange.Validation.Add _
    Type:=xlValidateList, _
    AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
    Formula1:=validValues
```

#### But I've seen that other locales needs comma separated

```vb
validValues = "a,b,c"
```

Essentially what I need is this, but I don't know how to determine 'id' in way that works in all locales.

```vb
' Internationalized delimiter
Dim id as String
id = ???
validValues = "a" & id & "b" & id & "c"
```

#### *Edit:*

*There seems to be a **"semicolon mode"** of Excel that I do not understand and which I cannot reproduce reliably. I had a certain instance of Excel that got into this mode and all code run inside it worked with semicolon and not comma. I wrote a project in this instance and it worked, I would have thought I just made a mistake if not for all the code that I now have to rewrite...*

*Any hints in order to figure this out is appreciated.*

#### Edit2:

After restarting Excel it changed it's mode to comma, I've been using it for a while but now this problem hit me again, Excel started using ';' (semicolon) instead of ','  (comma) as delimiter for my data validations.

This time I took a screenshot. Data validation is set to List.

Source is set to:

```
zero,one,both
```

[image]

This is the result, as you can see Excel does not care about my commas and displays all on the same line:

[image]

With source set like this it works:

```
zero;one;both
```

[image]

Result:

[image]

It is a mystery to me why Excel does this but I really need to find a way to make sure this never happens to my customer. *Any help appreciated!*

Comment: Are you sure, you have tested this already? `VBA` should not be locale dependent in `Formula` syntax. It should be `en_us` for this always. So `Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="1,2,3"` should work in all locales. At least it works with my German locale which also has a semicolon as list delimiter per default.

Comment: for me it's the same as for @AlexRichter: your code works even if _manual_ list validation would require ";" delimiter between elements to list

Comment: This is very strange. I just created a new file to verify your findings my test code did not run, my real code is quite big and I never actually ran the my testcase, so I facepalm myself until I verify that my real code actually runs with semicolon. Further testing and I find that the locale somehow makes excel run with either , or ;. I need to figure out the real difference, an open excel instance does not change but it seems to have to do with the locale that was set when excel was started.

Comment: I run through a win7 VirtualBox and I change language frequently on the Linux side between English and Swedish.

Comment: After lots of tries I'm unable to isolate the factor that makes it switch to semicolon instead of comma. My main work was in a certain instance of Excel and any code run within that instance, be it the main file or any new file, it would always only run with semicolon.
I have now closed that instance and now I have to rewrite my main code since it does not run anymore. I tried switching the languages in both Windows and Linux but so far I've not been able to make it go into "semicolon mode" again.
I need this file to work in any circumstance, so I need to figure this out. What could it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just dealed with a similar problem. I couldn't find a reason for why this happens, so I don't have a solution for good. Yet, I found a way around the problem that could be of use.

The only thing that you would need is to assign a valid value to the validated range **before** adding the validation.

After running your code, if the `.Formula1` argument worked with semicolons, then there is no problem at all. If it didn't, the `.Validation.Value` property of the range returns `False` and you can use that as a trigger to rerun your code, replacing the semicolon separated list by a comma separated one. Then just rerun the validation.

For example:

```
myRange.value = "a"    'Assuming "a" is a valid value contained in the validvalues string
If myRange.Validation.Value = False Then
    validvalues = replace(validvalues,";",",")
    myRange.validation.modify Formula1:= validvalues
End if
```

Then you can clear the range value if you do not wish to have a default value shown.

Comment: Thank you, I thought I was alone in the whole world in getting this problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, was the same issue here (mine Excel 2016, Windows, Poland)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for a delimiter that would work on multiple scenarios (please let me know if this is not your query).
comma, semicolon, are sometimes good delimiter but often they pose serious syntax and some other string related errors .

Triple question mark ??? is also not a good choice in this case.

I prefer to go with `|` (the pipe) in these situations.

Sorry for the long answer :)

Comment: I'm just looking for a construct to make this code run in whatever language, the question marks are just there to signify "I need some code here to make it work".

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft says you need to use commas in VBA

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/299490/data-validation-list-entries-all-on-one-line-in-excel

Comment: Please avoid posting link only answers.

Comment: @AjilO.  I included text with the explanation.  Microsoft says you have to use commas in VBA. That's really all there is to it.  If you follow the link all it  says is that VBA requires commas, and if you read the comments on the original post, you'll notice that it's likely his original code using semicolons never worked.

Comment: Yes I know that's how it is supposed to work, but Microsoft does not say what to do when what they say I need to do no longer works.

Comment: @JKAbrams - This has been explained.  If semicolon is your delimiter, you use semicolons when working in Excel dialogs, but in your VBA code, you need to use commas.  I would wager a large sum of money that if we looked at your VBA code, there would be semicolons in it.