# Validation.Add Method Odd behaviour

Tags: vba, excel

### What I need:

A validation list for every `Column B` cell in adjacent `Column C` cell every time values in `Column B` are changed.

### What I've done so far:

I wrote a piece of **code** for **Main** `Worksheet_Change` that **works but not as intended**.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim iCell As Range
    Dim valTxt As String

    If Not Intersect(Target, _
                     Target.Parent.Columns("B"), _
                     Target.Parent.Rows("10:65536")) _
                     Is Nothing Then
'       Loop through each cell in Intersection
        For Each iCell In Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Columns("B")).Cells
'           For non-blank values
            If iCell.Value <> "" Then
'                   ...
'                   Forming valTxt as "Header1,Header2,Header3"
'                   ...
'                   Testing
                    valTxt = "Header1,Header2,Header3"
'                   Validation list
                    With iCell.Offset(0, 1).Validation
'                       Delete previous
                        .Delete
'                       Create new based on valTxt
                        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
                             AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                             Formula1:=valTxt
                    End With
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Sub Test()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Range("B10").Value = "ProductName1"
End Sub
```

### Does it work or not?

#### Yes

Whenever I input new **ProductName** manualy in `Column B`, I get correct validation list. It also works if I copy/paste several **Product Names** from another source into `Column B`

#### No (that is the source of my frustration)

Whenever the `Column B` values are changed from the scope of another procedure, the **validation list consists of one item which is a comma-separated string** as `Header1,Header2,Header3` instead of three different items `Header1  Header2  Header3`.
If I change ANY `Column B` value (even with <kbd>F2</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) **validation list in adjacent cell is instantly corrected**.
If I make a breakpoint in `Worksheet_Change` procedure and force it continue from there, **validation list is formed correctly as well**.

### Does anyone know the reason behind this odd behaviour?

### How can I possibly fix my code with minor adjustments?

```
With iCell.Offset(0, 1).Validation
    iCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Left(valTxt, InStr(1, valTxt, ";") - 1)
    If Not .Value Then _
        .Modify Formula1:=Replace(valTxt, ";", ",")
    iCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
End With
```

Based on solution of @LucianoFerreira to another question, I tryed to incorporate some code but it didn't work (validation List consists of one item nonetheless).

Comment: Can you please create a [mcve] and kick all things out of your code that are not necessarily needed to reproduce your issue?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Done (I think? Not sure what I could do more).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mystery Excel semicolon mode for data validation, stops recognizeing standard comma for unknown reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40079711/mystery-excel-semicolon-mode-for-data-validation-stops-recognizeing-standard-co)

Comment: @LucianoFerreira Thanks for the possible solution, but it didn't work for me unforunately.

Comment: I think the answer to the other post could have been a little ambiguous. Try this: `With iCell.Offset(0, 1).Validation
    iCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Left(valTxt, InStr(1, valTxt, ",") - 1)
    If Not .Value Then _
        .Modify Formula1:=Replace(valTxt, ",", ";")
    iCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
End With` Let me know if this works, I just swapped the commas and semicolons :)

Comment: @LucianoFerreira Didn't work out. Though I had my doubts about it in the first place, since I use semicolons and should be swapping them, not commas.

Comment: @AntiDrondert, sorry mate. I'll see if I can think of something.

Comment: @LucianoFerreira Thanks for the help nonetheless.